# can't login ubuntu but can ssh to it

Tags: pam, environment-variables

The last few lines from `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Jan  9 22:59:57 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet5.so
Jan  9 22:59:57 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "miranda"
Jan  9 23:00:23 miranda-OptiPlex-790 dbus[807]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
```

I was trying to add a new variable to system enviroment.
I added one line to `/etc/enviroment`. Now I have sshed to the machine and removed the line. It looks like this now:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

But I still can't login.

Guest Session works with no problem.

My problem is similar to this one:
https://serverfault.com/questions/380917/cant-log-in-locally-but-ssh-works

He end up reinstalling the OS, I hope there is a still a way to save mine...

There is also another post about a similar problem:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/can%27t-login-over-console-but-can-ssh-in-740310/

But the link to solution doesn't work anymore.

---

Tried suggestions here:
[cannot login into locked Ubuntu 14.04 session Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758696/cannot-login-into-locked-ubuntu-14-04-session-unity)

After reinstalling a bunch of things:

```
apt-get install --reinstall kwalletmanager
apt-get install libpam-kwallet4 libpam-kwallet5
service lightdm restart
```

The new `auth.log` shows:

```
Jan 10 00:05:10 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user miranda by (uid=0)
Jan 10 00:05:10 miranda-OptiPlex-790 systemd-logind[796]: New session c32 of user miranda.
Jan 10 00:05:10 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet: pam_sm_open_session
Jan 10 00:05:10 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet: final socket path: /tmp/kwallet_miranda.socket
Jan 10 00:05:10 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet: Impossible to write walletKey to walletPipe
Jan 10 00:05:10 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet5: pam_sm_open_session
Jan 10 00:05:10 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm:session): pam_kwallet5: final socket path: /tmp/kwallet5_miranda.socket
Jan 10 00:05:11 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm-greeter:setcred): (null): pam_sm_setcred
Jan 10 00:05:11 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:setcred): (null): pam_sm_setcred
Jan 10 00:05:11 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Jan 10 00:05:11 miranda-OptiPlex-790 systemd-logind[796]: New session c33 of user lightdm.
Jan 10 00:05:11 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm-greeter:session): (null): pam_sm_open_session
Jan 10 00:05:11 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet(lightdm-greeter:session): pam_kwallet: open_session called without kwallet_key
Jan 10 00:05:11 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:session): (null): pam_sm_open_session
Jan 10 00:05:11 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_kwallet5(lightdm-greeter:session): pam_kwallet5: open_session called without kwallet5_key
Jan 10 00:05:11 miranda-OptiPlex-790 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "miranda"
Jan 10 00:05:22 miranda-OptiPlex-790 dbus[807]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
```

---

I'm not sure how to change the `lightdm` configuration

```
root@miranda-OptiPlex-790:/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d# ls
root@miranda-OptiPlex-790:/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d# cd ..
root@miranda-OptiPlex-790:/etc/lightdm# ls
lightdm.conf.d  users.conf
root@miranda-OptiPlex-790:/etc/lightdm# cat users.conf
#
# User accounts configuration
#
# NOTE: If you have AccountsService installed on your system, then LightDM will
# use this instead and these settings will be ignored
#
# minimum-uid = Minimum UID required to be shown in greeter
# hidden-users = Users that are not shown to the user
# hidden-shells = Shells that indicate a user cannot login
#
[UserList]
minimum-uid=500
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Should I try this solution?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337697/pbis-auth-log-requirement-user-ingroup-nopasswdlogin-not-met-by-user-administ

Edit `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` and remove `nopasswdlogin` from this line:

```
auth    sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup nopasswdlogin
```

Comment: `requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "miranda"` is a dead giveaway. Either add your user to that group or remove the directive from your lightdm config.

Comment: I'm a bit cautious to change stuff I don't understand now, as I'm too scared that a wrong move may lock myself out completely. Could u plz give me more instructions?

Answer (score 4):

In the end the method here saved the day:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/964607

I googled a bit to find out how to do it:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/300682/what-is-the-xauthority-file

The exact steps:

`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` when I'm in the login screen.

```
chown miranda:miranda .Xauthority
```

`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F7`

Some Explaination:

change `miranda` to your username.

Ctrl+Alt+F1 to F6 are the virtual consoles provided by the getty/agetty programs. Ctrl+Alt+F7 is the console where your X server is running.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/157617/reverting-from-ctrl-alt-f1

Use `ls -la .Xauthority` to confirm if that is the problem.

Comment: I needed `chown -R username:username ~username` to resolve things

Comment: What if ~/.Xauthority doesn't exist?